# MySQL Select timestamp column greater than

Tags: mysql

I have columns `movie_id`,`date_time` which is a timestamp column.

I'm attempting trying to fetch results but nothing is being returned.

```
movie_id    date_time
 2304       2018-08-24 17:43:34
 2405       2018-08-22 15:40:43
 3498       2018-08-23 11:13:20
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT b.* FROM movies b
    WHERE b.date_time>'2018-08-19 00:00:00'
```

Why aren't all the rows being returned?

Comment: Are you sure column has `TIMESTAMP` data type and not string?

Comment: yes, column is `timestamp`

Comment: `WHERE b.date_time>TIMESTAMP('2018-08-19 00:00:00')`

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try using  str_to_date() for convert the string

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM movies b
WHERE b.date_time> str_to_date('2018-08-19 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

```
SELECT b.* FROM movies b
    WHERE b.date_time> UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-08-19 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get them using the date function

```
Where date(date_time) > '2018-08-19'
```

Should work this way

Comment: Hi. Not sure exactly what you meant. But yes, you would need an index, like with any other column you're planing on filtering.

Comment: "Hi. Not sure exactly what you meant. But yes, you would need an index," `date(date_time) > '2018-08-19'` can't make use of a index even if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.* FROM movies b
    WHERE Convert(datetime,b.date_time,103)>Convert(datetime,'2018-08-19 00:00:00',103)
```